# Convert LINQ join query to SQL inline join query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to convert LINQ join to simple SQL inline join query.

This is my LINQ query.

```
 public ProjectTaskList_Deleted GetTaskToBeDeletedByTaskID(int ProjectTaskID)
    {
        ProjectTaskList_Deleted list=null;
        try
        {
            using (var db = new Cubicle_EntityEntities())
            {
                list = (from a in db.ProjectTaskList_Deleted where a.ProjectTaskID == ProjectTaskID select a).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: what SQL have you formed yet ?

Comment: select * from project join projectlist on projects.projectID=projectTaskLists.projectID where projectTaskLists.IsDelieverable==true and projects.companyId=?

Answer (score 3):

This is the equivalent `SQL`:

```
 select p.ProjectID ProjectID, p.ProjectName + ' - ' + p.ProjectCode as ProjectName
 from
 Projects p join ProjectTaskLists pl
 on p.ProjectID = pl.ProjectID
 where pl.IsDeliverable = true and p.CompanyId = @CompanyId
```

where `@CompanyId` is a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is the SQL Normal query:

```
select p.ProjectID, p.ProjectName + ' - ' + p.ProjectCode as ProjectName from Projects p
Inner join ProjectTaskLists pl on  pl.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
where pl.IsDeliverable == true && p.CompanyId == @CompanyId
```